# Synthesize a Tesla Coil ??

Tags: electricity, tesla-coil, synthesis

Hey everyone!

After I finished the sword I asked you a few days ago, a doubt remained that I cant get off my head: How could you synthesize the electric jolt created by a tesla coil? The final result I'm looking for is something like this:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3b6I0Rzl0ss

I believe that If I could get a single jolt, I could layer a buch of them with different envelope settings, pitch, flanging and other stuff to achieve that Tesla coil.

What do you think guys?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you get a recording of a tesla coil? Or just get something that resembles enough of the sound that you're looking for.

Of course you can then stick the sample to a granular synthesizer, for example, to start with. Or just combine it with other fitting sounds, add effects etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm with him, there are a good bit of tesla coil recordings. If i was forced at gunpoint to do that though, I might try FM8 with some enveloped and modulated noise maybe? I've had some okay luck stumbling into electrical noise when messing with FM'ing the noise operator on that in some weird ways.

textarea[link text](http://electro-music.com/forum/topic-21825.html)textarea

Answer (score 1):

Check out Tonsturms Electricity package, looks like an awful lot of what you're looking for!

http://www.tonsturm.com/Soundpacks/files/Electricity.html